# Auto create entity - strange name of unique

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I have problem with auto creating entity by hibernate. I have this property:

```
("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
```

Then in my for example user class on the filed mail have following annotation:

```
@Column(unique = true)
private String email;
```

The whole entity for user is creating correctly, but the unique value name in database is: "uk6dotkott2kjsp8vw4d0m25fb7". Is any way to change this name from hiberante? For example "unique" or "unique_mail"? Thanks for response. However the primary key name is normal, in my case it is: "users_pkey".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [@UniqueConstraint](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html) annotation, at the class level, that has an optional argument `name` to define the unique constraint on `email` column.

Comment: Thanks it works. Solution in my case: uniqueConstraints =
{ @UniqueConstraint(columnNames =
{ "email" }, name = "un_email") })